# Count preceding and following rows >=10

Tags: python, pandas

I have a spectrum and would like to identify the different channels. The channels can be distinguished from the edges between the channels by the level (`val`).

I have created a simplified table that contains the column `val`. Now I want to calculate how many rows before and after contain values greater or equal `10`.

Example:

[image: example]

- 1. row: `val = 10` , followed by `11, 10, 2, 3` -> `next = 2` and `prev = 0`
- 2. row: `val = 11`, followed by `10, 2, 3`, before was `10` -> `next = 1`, `prev = 1`
- 3. row: `val = 10`, followed by `2, 3`, before was `11, 10` -> `next = 0`, `prev = 2`
- 4. row: `val = 2`, followed by `3`, before was `10, 11, 10` -> `next = 0`, `prev = 3`
- 5. row: `val = 2`, before was `2, 10, 11, 10` -> `prev = 0`

In real-world data a channel contains about 20-30 measurement points, so I hope that there is a solution to solve this without creating 30 shifts in both directions. And also not all channels have the same width, so it should be dynamic.

Happy for any help or hint, thank you very much.

---

## MWE

```
import pandas as pd

df_test = pd.DataFrame({"val":[10,11,10,2,3,10,10,10,4,6,11,7,10,10,11,10,11,10]})

df_test["prev"] = [0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,0,1,2,3,4,5]
df_test["next"] = [2,1,0,0,3,2,1,0,0,1,0,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]

+----+-------+--------+--------+
|    |   val |   prev |   next |
|----+-------+--------+--------|
|  0 |    10 |      0 |      2 |
|  1 |    11 |      1 |      1 |
|  2 |    10 |      2 |      0 |
|  3 |     2 |      3 |      0 |
|  4 |     3 |      0 |      3 |
|  5 |    10 |      0 |      2 |
|  6 |    10 |      1 |      1 |
|  7 |    10 |      2 |      0 |
|  8 |     4 |      3 |      0 |
|  9 |     6 |      0 |      1 |
| 10 |    11 |      0 |      0 |
| 11 |     7 |      1 |      6 |
| 12 |    10 |      0 |      5 |
| 13 |    10 |      1 |      4 |
| 14 |    11 |      2 |      3 |
| 15 |    10 |      3 |      2 |
| 16 |    11 |      4 |      1 |
| 17 |    10 |      5 |      0 |
+----+-------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Vectorized Solution

```
def count(vals, direction):
    if direction == 'prev':
        vals = vals[::-1]

    arr = np.tile(vals, (len(vals), 1))

    mask = arr >= 10
    mask[np.tril_indices_from(mask)] = True

    ix = mask.argmin(axis=1) 
    ix[ix == 0] = len(ix)

    result = ix - np.arange(len(ix)) - 1
    return result[::-1] if direction == 'prev' else result
```

#### Result

```
count(df.val, 'prev')
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

count(df.val, 'next')
# array([2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

#### Working of function explained

For simplicity let's consider a sample dataframe with 5 rows and `direction` set to `next`, now I'll walk through steps defined in the function:

```
df
#     val
# 0   10
# 1   11
# 2   10
# 3    2
# 4    3
```

Tile the values into 2D matrix. *Notice that the main diagonal represent the actual values from the original column*

```
arr = np.tile(vals, (len(vals), 1))
# array([[10, 11, 10,  2,  3],
#        [10, 11, 10,  2,  3],
#        [10, 11, 10,  2,  3],
#        [10, 11, 10,  2,  3],
#        [10, 11, 10,  2,  3]])
```

Create a boolean mask to identify the values `>= 10` then mask the values in lower triangle with `True` because we are only interested in values to the right of main diagonal

```
mask
# array([[ True,  True,  True, False, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True, False, False]])

mask[np.tril_indices_from(s)] = True
# array([[ True,  True,  True, False, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Find the index of first false value along each row using `argmin` and if there's no false value (e.g. row 5) in this case set the index to the length of array

```
ix = mask.argmin(axis=1) 
ix[ix == 0] = len(ix)
# array([3, 3, 3, 4, 5])
```

Subtract the index (`ix`) from the index of diagonal value to calculate the distance which which actually represents the number of True values satifying the condition

```
result = ix - np.arange(len(ix)) - 1
# array([2, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding Marco!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works:

```
def count_prev_next(row, df):
    current_index = row.name
    
    if current_index == 0:
        prev_count = 0
    else:
        try:
            prev_count = (
                pd.DataFrame(df.loc[:current_index-1, "val"] >= 10)[::-1] 
                .reset_index(drop=True)
                .query("val == False")
                .index[0]
            )
        except:
            prev_count = current_index
    
    if current_index == df.shape[0]:
        next_count = 0
    else:
        try:
            next_count = (
                pd.DataFrame(df.loc[current_index+1:, "val"] >= 10) 
                .reset_index(drop=True)
                .query("val == False")
                .index[0]
            )
        except:
            next_count = df.shape[0] - current_index - 1
    
    return pd.Series({"prev": prev_count, "next": next_count})

df_test[["prev", "next"]] = df_test.apply(count_prev_next, axis=1, args=(df_test,))
```

Let it open for a while to see if somebody has a better idea.